# VB.NET WPF How to create UserControls for Forms that function like the regular Form controls inside a Form

Tags: wpf, vb.net, winforms, xaml, user-controls

EDIT: My last question wasn't great, so I changed it here. Hopefully this explanation will be better!

I'm trying to create `UserControls` that work like the regular `Form Controls` in a `Form`, or as close as possible.

For my example, I have a `UserControl` that has inside it a < TextBox >. I want to give this 'UserControl' all the functions and properties that are appropriate for a `TextBox`, so that it can mimic a regular `TextBox` inside my `Form`. This way I can get and set its properties and call its `Events` from within my `Form` code.

In my `Form1`, I have a regular `TextBox` on top, a regular `Button` beside it and a `ElementHost` for my `UserControl` Textbox.

I want to type in some string into the top `TextBox`, click my add `Button` and have to text from the top `TextBox` passed into my `UserControl TextBox` that is inside the `ElementHost` as I'm sure that's the only way you can display the `UserControl` in a `Form`!

This is what I've got so far. I don't know if this is the correct approach as I'm new to all this.

**UCTextbox.xaml - UserControl**

```
<UserControl x:Class="UCTextbox"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
         xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
         xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
         xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UCTextboxTest"
         mc:Ignorable="d" 
         d:DesignHeight="50" d:DesignWidth="300">
<Grid>
     <TextBox x:Name="txtBox" Text="{Binding Text}"/>   
</Grid>
```

**UCTextbox.xaml.vb - back code**

```
Public Class UCTextbox
  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.'
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.'
    Me.DataContext = Me
  End Sub

  'Get/Set the text value of my < TextBox > UserControl'
  Private textValue As String
  Public Property Text() As String
    Get
        Return textValue
    End Get
    Set(ByVal value As String)
        textValue = value
    End Set
  End Property

' MORE PROPERTIES AND EVENTS WILL BE ADDED - KEEPING IT SIMPLE FOR NOW'
End Class
```

**Form1 Layout**

[Form1 Layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/81OuV.png)

**Form1 Class**

```
Public Class Form1
  'Create UserControl uc so that Button can reference it'
  Dim uc As UCTextbox

  Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.'
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.'

    'Tried creating UserControl-uc textbox and added it into ElementHost-hostTextbox here instead'
    'Dim uc As UCTextbox = New UCTextbox()'
    'hostTextbox.Child = uc'
    'Me.Controls.Add(hostTextbox)'

  End Sub

  Private Sub Form1_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load

    uc = New UCTextbox()
    hostTextbox.Child = uc

    uc.Text = "Dog" 'Using uc function .Text only seem to work inside Form1_Load'
  End Sub


  Private Sub btnAdd_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAdd.Click

   'This does not work here'
    uc.Text = tbxTop.Text
    hostTextbox.Child = uc 'Do I have to reapply the UserControl to the ElementHost each time I make a change to uc'
  End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: WPF controls can only be added to WPF `Windows`. If you want to add a control to a Windows Forms `Form` then you have to create a Windows Forms control.  There is a Windows Forms control that you can add to a form and then host a WPF control within it but that is a somewhat painful way to go.

Comment: I've edited my original question, but I know about about `ElementHost` that is used for `UserControl`s. I just need to know how to get it to work inside the `Form`s code and how I can gain access to the functions and properties of the `UserControl`.